# In ssh session, emacs cursor color always matches color of text at point

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, emacs, fonts, command-line-interface

When I use Emacs in X, it has millions of colors. When I SSH into an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04, it only has 8 colors.

The problem is that the cursor is always the same color as the text at point. If I move from white text to black text, the cursor changes from white to black. When I evaluate (set-cursor-color "blue"), nothing happens. I can change the background color, but not the cursor color.

My own machine is running Kubuntu 16.04 -- that is, Ubuntu 16.04 plus KDE. The terminal app I'm using to SSH is called Konsole.

Comment: Assuming Konsole *can* support more colours than that, you can probably set your `TERM` environment variable to something better. I don't know whether Konsole is compatible, but some terminals work nicely with `export TERM=xterm-256color`, so you could give that a try. I suggest investigating whether there's something more appropriate for Konsole.

Comment: Should that matter if there are already colors available? I can change the background color, e.g. with (set-background-color "blue") -- just not the cursor color. (Whereas using Emacs in X I can do both.)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention! I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The cursor colour in a *terminal* is outside of Emacs' control (the cursor face is for X displays only), but depending on the terminal there may be escape sequences you can send to manipulate it. I don't use Konsole, so YMMV, but the following works in the default Ubuntu terminal. If it doesn't work for you, check the Konsole documentation and see whether you can adapt it to suit.

```el
(defun my-terminal-cursor-color (color)
  "Sets the terminal cursor colour by sending the appropriate escape sequence."
  (interactive
   (list (read-color "Color (white): " nil :allow-empty)))
  (when (string= color "")
    (setq color "white"))
  (send-string-to-terminal
   (concat "\033]12;" color "\007")))
```

Comment: Aha! That is helpful, thanks. I was hoping to be able to change cursor color from any terminal on any platform. It sounds like displaying a message in the status bar will be easier. (It is to indicate whether the user is in move-submode or edit-submode.)